# Gate spike in Synchronous Boost converter

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, boost, gate-driving

I'm trying to build a synchronous boost converter. I'm getting the following spike in the gate. Yellow is gate voltage and blue is drain to source voltage. How to get rid of this spike in the gate?

I have tried adding a capacitor to gate to source, but it slows down the mosfet switching speed and device heats up.

Is there anything I can do to reduce this spike without slowing down the mosfet switching speed?

[image]

Comment: Hello Prashanth, could you post a schematic?

Comment: Also the board layout would be helpful.  This could be extra inductance in the traces due to layout.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a layout issue, but could be that your drive circuit is not low enough output impedance. That would allow the miller capacitor to drive the gate signal as drain voltage rises. If you have a gate resistor, try lowering it or paralleling it with a small capacitor.